# How to insert images in rows of ultimatelistctrl (wxPython)

Tags: wxpython

I have looked long and hard at the ULC demo, and it is rather complicated.
Can someone please show me how to add an image to each of the rows?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s the same as the wxPython Classic wx.ListCtrl:

listCtrl.InsertImageStringItem(row_index, label, imageId)

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.html#wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.InsertImageStringItem

Where imageId is the image index inside your wx.ImageList that you previously assigned to your ULC.

Comment: Got it, thanks. One final related question. Is it possible to put padding around the image if it is too close to the text? Or is that best done in the image itself?